# How do I install a custom local font?

Tags: fonts

I am trying to install a custom local font but it doesn't look like it's working.

style.css:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "TTNorms";
  src: url("./fonts/TTNorms.eot");
  src: url("./fonts/TTNorms.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("./fonts/TTNorms.woff2") format("woff2"),
    url("./fonts/TTNorms.woff") format("woff"),
    url("./fonts/TTNorms.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("./fonts/TTNorms.svg#TTNorms-Regular") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

My fonts folder:

```
fonts
├── TTNorms-Regular.eot
├── TTNorms-Regular.svg
├── TTNorms-Regular.ttf
├── TTNorms-Regular.woff
├── TTNorms-Regular.woff2
```

However, when I try to set any element's `font-family: "TTNorms"` it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your filenames are wrong. :) For example in your CSS you're asking for "TTNorms.eot" but in your fonts folder the file is actually called "TTNorms-Regular.eot".

Comment: omg... I'm an idiot. It works after changing them!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably how you're referencing the fonts from the css. Assuming "style.css" and "fonts" directories are on the same level, your code should work. Are you using a bundler (Webpack or Gulp)? Either could resolve your issue quickly.